# Can I still get Factory Zero achivement if I don't save anyone in DE:HR Missing Link?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

I'm going for Factory Zero achievement, and there's point in main quest where I get a choice who to save. If I wait for timer to expire, next quest will automatically start. Has anyone done that and got the achievement?

(my assumption is not based on Factory Zero description, but I'm not 100% sure, and Factory Zero is painful to do)

Answer (score 3):

The Factory Zero achievement is not about saving people. It's about adopting a particular playstyle.

The achievement is as follows:

> You survived The Missing Link using no Praxis kits, weapons, or explosives. Whoa.

This means:

- Do not allocate any Praxis points, whether acquired through levelling up or after collecting a Praxis kit
- Do not fire any weapons
- Do not throw grenades or place mines or other explosive *item*

You can however, use environmental explosives (throwing explosive barrels), use items that give you health, buy or sell any items, equip/aim/reload weapons. You can also set off alarms or make people suspicious. Regarding not firing weapons: takedowns (both lethal and non-lethal) are not considered weapons and can be used freely.